# Having issues to get data from json file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, web

I have 2 JSON files. One is for food types for e.g, Starters, Main Course, Beverages etc and the other is for displaying the details for each food item like the food name, food type, food description and price.

I want to select a food category from one JSON file and make an AJAX call to load another JSON file based on the first one in order to display the required food for that category. However, I am not getting the information.

```html
<?php
  $url = 'http://localhost/trial2/buildFoodCategoriesJSON.php';
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $obj = json_decode($json, false);
?>

<p>Select a food category to view corresponding details
  <select id="foodCat">
    <option value=''></option>
    <?php foreach($obj as $foodCategory) {
      echo "<option value='" . $foodCategory->Food_Type . "'>". $foodCategory->Food_Type . "</option>";
    } ?>
  </select>
</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select#foodCat').change(function() {
    var fCategory = $(this).val();

    if (fCategory != '') { //if user did not choose blank
      var url = "http://localhost/trial2/getFoodItemsJSON.php?Food_Type=";
      url = url + fCategory;

      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //no output
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
          foodName = obj['Food_Name'];
          foodDesc = obj['Food_Description'];
          foodPrice = obj['Food_Price(Rs)'];
          alert(foodName); //no output
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Note that if your JS comments are really spanning multiple lines like that, then that will be causing at least one of your issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there are no errors in console :/ I added the comments just here

Comment: In that case the rest of your code looks fine. Check in the network tab of dev tools to see what the response text and status code of the request is

Comment: Unless your itemlist is very large, it might be an idea to fetch and store the whole list on the first call and use a simple `.filter()` function to select and display the items you need. It might be problematic if u change the categories very fast and u stack up the `getJSON()` calls

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the statuses returned 200 and i dnt see response text :/

Comment: @Lapskaus how shall i do that?

Comment: That will most likely not solve your issue and was just a hint that triggering alot of ajax calls - which getJSON() is - is often problematic due to the asynchronous type. can you post the content of your `getFoodItemsJSON.php` ?

Comment: `the statuses returned 200 and i dnt see response text` than that's the issue. You need to debug the response from your PHP, not the JS code

Comment: @Lapskaus It is working now! I closed my browser completely, cleared the cache and now it's working. Thanks for your help though